# Why Svelte is called a compiler while other frameworks are called transpilers

Tags: javascript, svelte, javascript-framework, transpiler

I recently got this question in school about frontend javascript frameworks, "Why are other frameworks that convert code into vanilla javascript called transpilers, but Svelte is called a compiler?". I couldn't find anything about it on the internet and I don't really understand it. Could someone please explain it to me in simple terms?

Comment: What are these other frameworks you speak of? Can you give an example?

Comment: @smac89 I was asked this question when I was talking about React, Vue and Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Technically Svelte is also a transpiler. The main distinction between the terms is that a transpiler converts source code to source code while a compiler should convert source code to machine code (much more low level).

Svelte outputs JS, which is still a high level language but at the same time, the code is not exactly what you would call "human readable" and JS is the lowest level web front-end language that you can compile to with the exception of WebAssembly (which is not always an option due its limitations, like not being able to access the DOM directly).

Comment: The typescript compiler doesn't convert typescript syntax to machine code. Also are you saying that a library such as uglifyjs is a compiler?

Comment: TypeScript is also a transpiler. When "compiler" is used in front end tech that is compiling to JS, that is probably due to the fact that JS is the lowest level that can be compiled to (with the exception of WebAssembly, which has some limitations). Minifiers technically also fall into this category.

Comment: It seems then that every "transpiler" on the web is also a compiler to some degree